# Django: show list of many to many items in the admin interface

Tags: python, django

This might be a simple question, but i can't seem to grasp it.

I have two simple models in models.py: Service and Host. Host.services has a m2m relationship with Service.
In other words, a host has several services and one service can reside on multiple hosts; a basic m2m.

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    servicename = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.servicename

    class Admin:
            pass

class Host(models.Model):
    #...
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
    #...

    def get_services(self):
            return self.services.all()

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.hostname

    class Admin:
            pass
```

admin.py

```
from cmdb.hosts.models import Host
from django.contrib import admin


class HostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('get_services',)

admin.site.register(Host, HostAdmin)
```

Now when i open the page where all the host's columns are listed the 'service' column displays the output like:

Get services

`[<Service: the_service-1>, <Service: the_service-2>]`

Instead of:

Services

the_service-1

the_service-2
etc.

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should change `get_services` to something like:

```
def get_services(self):
    return "\n".join([s.servicename for s in self.services.all()])
```

**Update:** Try using `\n` as the separator rather than `<br/>`, as the output of get_services is being escaped.

Comment: +1. Wish there was a better way to do this than hardcoding HTML formatting in a model method.

Comment: It's just one way. Another would be to render a template to string and return the result - this would move the HTML to the template. However, this is for the Django admin - which is for sysadmins rather than end-users - hence maybe the utilitarian approach is OK.